# dtype is ignored when using multilevel columns

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, header

When using DataFrame.read_csv with multi level columns (read with `header=`) pandas seems to ignore the `dtype=` keyword.
Is there a way to make pandas use the passed types?
I am reading large data sets from CSV and therefore try to read the data already in the correct format to save CPU and memory.

I tried passing a dict using dtype with tuples as well as strings. It seems that dtype expects strings. At least I observed, that if I pass the level 0 keys the types are assigned, but unfortunately that would mean that all columns with the same level 0 label would get the same type. In the esample below columns (A, int16) and (A, int32) would get type *object* and (B, float32) and (B, int16) would get *float32*.

```
import pandas as pd
    df=  pd.DataFrame({
        ('A', 'int16'):   pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int16'),
        ('A', 'int32'):   pd.Series([132, 232, 332, 432], dtype='int32'), 
        ('B', 'float32'): pd.Series([1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04], dtype='float32'),
        ('B', 'int16'):   pd.Series([21, 22, 23, 24], dtype='int16')})
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('test_df.csv')
    print(df.dtypes)
    <i># full column name tuples with level 0/1 labels don't work</i>
    df_new= pd.read_csv(
        'test_df.csv',
        header=list(range(2)),
        dtype = {
            ('A', 'int16'): 'int16', 
            ('A', 'int32'): 'int32'
        })
    print(df_new.dtypes)
    <i># using the level 0 labels for dtype= seems to work</i>
    df_new2= pd.read_csv(
        'test_df.csv', 
        header=list(range(2)), 
        dtype={
            'A':'object', 
            'B': 'float32'
        })
    print(df_new2.dtypes)
```

I'd expect the second `print(df.dtypes)` to output the same column types as the first `print(df.dtypes)`, but it does not seem to use the `dtype=` argument at all and infers the types resulting in much more memory intense types.

Was I missing something?

Thank you in advance Jottbe

Comment: In version 1.2.2 this problem still persists. But it only seems to affect the c-engine. If `engine='python'` is specified, the types are applied properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, that is also present in the current version of pandas. I filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42446).

But also for the current version, there is a workaround. It works perfectly, if the engine is switched to python:

```
df_new= pd.read_csv(
    'test_df.csv',
    header=list(range(2)),
    engine='python',
    dtype = {
        ('A', 'int16'): 'int16', 
        ('A', 'int32'): 'int32'
    })
print(df_new.dtypes)
```

The output is:

```
Unnamed: 0_level_0  Unnamed: 0_level_1      int64
A                   int16                   int16
                    int32                   int32
B                   float32               float64
                    int16                   int64
```

So the "A-columns" are typed as specified in `dtypes`.